# igtbl_getActiveRow is not defined

Tags: infragistics

I have simple code in my javascript of an aspx page:

```js
var activeRow= igtbl_getActiveRow("gridName");
```

I get the error igtbl_getActiveRow is not defined.

I am using Infragistics4.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.v11.1.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I would try to first get the grid and then the row.

```
var grid = igtbl_getGridById('gridId');
var activeRow = grid.getActiveRow();
```

or

```
var activeRow = igtbl_getGridById('gridId').getActiveRow();
```